# Real time location data of players via customize JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I would like to achieve the 'real time' location data of players and their movement displaying in map. I have added the following code below.
Could someone help me how to get real time updated 'GEOJson' location data of player and a way to customise using JavaScript function to display in map

```
enter code here

var geojson=[
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [174.83, -36.90]
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": "John1",
      "description": "Mt Wellington, Auckland",
      "marker-color": "#fc4353",
      "marker-size": "large"

    }   

}

];


L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
  .setView([-36.90, 174.83,], 11)
  .featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);


  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('geojson')
    // Once this layer loads, we set a timer to load it again in a few seconds.
    .on('ready', run)
    .addTo(map);

function run() {
    featureLayer.eachLayer(function(l) {
        map.panTo(l.getLatLng());
    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        featureLayer.loadURL('geojson');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to provide real-time updates of the geo data. You can also have a look at [leaflet-realtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-realtime) that seems to do exactly what you want.